# LifecycleCallback called in ArrayCollection

Tags: symfony

Sorry for the title, I don't know how to say it.

I've two Entity: Strain that have a OneToMany relation on Tubes, and a cascade={"persist", "remove"} attribute.
For the twice entity I define their names on the fly with a PrePersist callback. But, it's work only for the Tube entity, on the Strain entity I've a problem because its name is defined on the first tube name. And I think PrePersist is used on Strain before Tubes. Then if Tubes have not name, Strain have a null name.

If I do a foreach while in the controller to persist each tube one by one before persist the strain, it works fine. But I don't really like it. Can we configure it somewhere, like a priority order to PrePersist ?

My entities:

Tube

```
class Tube
{
  /**
   * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\Strain", inversedBy="tubes")
   */
  private $gmoStrain;

  ...


  // SETTERS & GETTERS

  public function setStrain(Strain $strain)
  {
    $this->strain = $strain;

    return $this;
  }

  public function getStrain()
  {
    return $this->strain;
  }

  ...

  //LifecycleCallback

/**
 * Before persist.
 *
 * @ORM\PrePersist()
 */
public function prePersist()
{
    // Give a name to the tube
    // The name is composed like this:
    // ProjectPrefix_BoxLetter_xxxType

    // ProjectPrefix (The prefix of the first Tube)
    $projectPrefix = $this->getBox()->getProject()->getPrefix();

    // BoxLetter (idem, the first tube)
    $boxLetter = $this->getBox()->getBoxLetter();

    // In array the first cell is 0, in real box, it's 1
    $cell = $this->cell + 1;

    // Adapt the boxCell like: 1 => 001, 10 => 010, 100 => 100, never more than 999
    if ($cell < 10) {
        $boxCell = '00'.$cell;
    } elseif ($cell > 99) {
        $boxCell = $cell;
    } else {
        $boxCell = '0'.$cell;
    }

    // Type Letter
    $lastLetter = $this->getStrain()->getType()->getLetter();

    // Generate the tube name
    $this->name = $projectPrefix.'_'.$boxLetter.$boxCell.$lastLetter;
}
}
```

Strain:

```
class Strain
{
    /**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\Tube", mappedBy="strain", cascade={"persist", "remove"})
 */
  private $tubes;

  ...

  //SETTERS & GETTERS

  public function addTube(Tube $tube)
  {
      if (!$this->tubes->contains($tube)) {
          $tube->setGmoStrain($this);
          $this->tubes->add($tube);
      }
  }

  public function removeTube(Tube $tube)
  {
      if ($this->tubes->contains($tube)) {
          $this->tubes->removeElement($tube);
      }
  }

  public function getTubes()
  {
      return $this->tubes;
  }

  ...

  //LifecycleCallback

/**
 * Before persist.
 *
 * @ORM\PrePersist()
 */
public function postPersist()
{
    // The automatic name of the strain is the name of the first tube
    // when the strain is registred the first time
    $this->systematicName = $this->getTubes()->first()->getName();
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to set the priority of the `prePersist` event, this can be done by using [Event Listeners and Subscribers](http://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine/event_listeners_subscribers.html) service instead of `@ORM\PrePersist` annotation.

First, create the Tube listener class for `prePresist` event:

```
// src/AppBundle/EventListener/TubeListener.php
namespace AppBundle\EventListener;

use Doctrine\ORM\Event\LifecycleEventArgs;
use AppBundle\Entity\Tube;

class TubeListener
{
    public function prePersist(LifecycleEventArgs $args)
    {
        $entity = $args->getEntity();

        if (!$entity instanceof Tube) {
            return;
        }

        $em = $args->getEntityManager();
        // do something with the Tube
    }
}
```

Next, registers the listener, by default if priority tag attribute is not provided then it's zore `0`:

```
services:
    app.event_listener.tube:
        class: AppBundle\EventListener\TubeListener
        tags:
            - { name: doctrine.event_listener, event: prePersist }
```

Later, create the second `Strain` listener class for the same `prePresist` event:

```
// src/AppBundle/EventListener/StrainListener.php
namespace AppBundle\EventListener;

use Doctrine\ORM\Event\LifecycleEventArgs;
use AppBundle\Entity\Strain;

class StrainListener
{
    public function prePersist(LifecycleEventArgs $args)
    {
        $entity = $args->getEntity();

        if (!$entity instanceof Strain) {
            return;
        }

        $em = $args->getEntityManager();
        // do something with the Strain (at this moment pre-persist Tube already called)
    }
}
```

Now, registers this listener with a minor priority than `TubeListener`:

```
services:
    app.event_listener.strain:
        class: AppBundle\EventListener\StrainListener
        tags:
            - { name: doctrine.event_listener, event: prePersist, priority: -5 }
```

Thus ensuring that the first `prePersist` event (with priority `0`) has been executed before the second (priority `-5`). This can be archived using Subscribers instead also.

Comment: Sorry to answer so late. I just tried it, but I've a blank page. I understand what you want to do. But here, I need to put my prePersist code in this page and not in the entity ? I've never used it, sorry.

Comment: It's okay, I juste need to remove @ORM\PrePersist in Strain, and keep it in Tube. Then I use an EventListener on Strain PrePersist and I do a foreach on Tubes and persist in, after what I call a function to generate the name of the strain.